# Meteor Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using meteor and I have my static files located in the public directory:

```
// Directory Structure

app
    app/.meteor
    app/server
    app/client
    app/packages
    app/lib
    app/public
        app/public/styles
        app/public/images
```

On my `index.html`, I have this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/styles/app.css"/>`

I still get this error:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/public/styles/app.css"`.

How can I work my way out of this? What's the proper usage of meteor's public directory?

Answer (score 7):

You're requesting the incorrect directory. Meteor is serving up HTML as it would with any path that does not point to a file.

The URL path should point to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/app.css"/>
```

Everything in `public` should map to `/`

Comment: My stylesheet is in `<link href="/client/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">` as it was recommended to move all stylesheets into this structure. How can I get rid of the same error?

Comment: Thanks! I wish I saw this an hour earlier!